# Degree of the Extension $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/n})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/n})$. Prove that $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=n$.

I know that this is asking to prove the dimension of the vector space $F$ over the field of scalars $\mathbb{Q}$ is $n$, and I'm aware the basis should be $\{1,2^{1/n},2^{2/n},\dots,2^{(n-1)/n}\}$, but I'm having a hard time showing explicitly *why* these are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and why they span.

Comment: Hint : use the fact that $X^n-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$

Comment: If $p(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$, and $a$ is some zero in an extension field $E\supseteq F$ then $F(a)\cong F[x]/<p(x)>$. This gets us that $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/n})\cong \mathbb{Q}/<x^n-2>$.

Where does this get us?

Comment: Well, it remains only to find a basis of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^n - 2)$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space

Comment: I think I got it, $B=\{[1],[x],\dots,[x^{n-1}]\}$. These are linearly independent because they can't be contained in $[0]$, as any linear combination cannot be a polynomial multiple of $x^n-2$ (the degrees are mismatched). The set clearly spans, so we're done?

Comment: Yes. The formal argument to prove that they span is euclidean division by $x^n -2$